# Passing an int to a function, then using that int to create an array

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I'm trying to create a textureLoader class for my openGL project and I can't initialize an array of textures inside of my class constructor because the the array won't accept anything unless it's a const int.

**To paint you a simple picture...**

```
myFunction(NUM)
  {
  GLuint textures[NUM];
  }
```

**My past Failures**

```
myConstructor(const int& num)
  {
   GLuint textures[num] //error: expression must have a constant value
  }
```

---

```
myConstructor(int num)
{
std::vector <GLuint> textures(num);//works but wait
glGenTextures(num, textures) // <--- doesn't work cause vectors. 
}
```

---

```
myConstructor(int num)
{
const int PLEASE_WORK = num;
GLuint textures[PLEASE_WORK]; // doesn't work.
```

Comment: What you tried (except the `vector` method) is called Variable-length arrays, which is supported in C99 but not in C++ IIRC.

Comment: I will look that up, thank you. I was thinking at least the third option should have worked.

Comment: it doesn't because the size of the array is not known during compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second options is close, you can get at the underlying array of the vector by calling `.data()`

```
myConstructor(int num)
{
    std::vector <GLuint> textures(num);
    glGenTextures(num, textures.data());
}
```

Assuming `glGenTextures` has a signature like

```
void glGenTextures(int, GLuint*)
```

I don't know much about this function, but be careful who owns that array. The `vector` will fall out of scope after your constructor so I'm hoping that `glGenTextures` will copy whatever it needs. Otherwise if the array needs to persist

```
myConstructor(int num)
{
    GLuint* textures = new GLuint[num];
    glGenTextures(num, textures);
}
```

But then I'm not sure who is supposed to clean up that memory.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I will keep the scope of those variables in mind. Is there any way to do it using a const int& or anything other than vectors? Or is that my only alternative.

Comment: FYI: [`std::vector::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) is c++11

Comment: @BryantheLion See the second half of my answer (using `new`), that is your alternative.

Comment: @Tas It is halfway through 2015, I would hope people are using (at least) C++11 compilers, otherwise they should make a point of specifying which compiler they are targeting.

Comment: Thanks Cory, I appreciate that, maybe I can delete that memory in the definiton of the destructor?

Comment: @BryantheLion Sure that is a valid option. Keep a pointer to that array as a member variable, then call `delete[] your_array` in your destructor.

Comment: Prior to C++11 you can use `num == 0 ? NULL : &textures[0]`